# Почему через почтовые программы подпись ломается

Tags: html

Сделал подпись. В браузере смотрится нормально, а вот когда открываешь через почтовые программы то все начинает ломаться.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      body {
        width: 531px;
        height: 290px;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      td.firstdiv {
        float: left;
        max-width: 76px;
        height: 135px; 
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 45px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-top:0px; 
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
      }

      td.seconddiv {
        float: left;
        height: 155px;
        max-width: 253px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 45px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px; 
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px; 
      }

      td.thirddiv {
        float: left;
        max-width: 355px;
        height: 116px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px; 
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
      }

      td.fourdiv {
        float: inherit;
        max-width: 230px;
        height: 176px;
        margin-left:0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-top:146px; 
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
      }

      .whois {
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 36px;
        padding-top: 0px; 
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
      }

      .adress {
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px; 
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
      }

      .site {
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px; 
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
      }

      .person {
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px; 
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        padding-right:0px;
      }

      .icons {
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px; 
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        padding-right:0px;
      }

      .social1 {
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 13px;
        margin-bottom: 9px;
        padding-top:0px; 
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
      }

      .social2 {
        float: right;
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 13px;
        margin-bottom: 9px;
        padding-top: 0px; 
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
     }

     .avalogo {
       padding-left: 0px;
       margin-left: 0px;
       margin-right: 0px;
       margin-top: 0px;
       margin-bottom: 0px;
       padding-top: 0px; 
       padding-left: 0px;
       padding-bottom: 0px;
       padding-right: 0px;
     }

     .phone {
       text-decoration: none;
       color: black;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table cellspacing="0" class="maindiv">
      <tr>
        <td class="firstdiv">
          <img class="avalogo" src="bhttp://contrabanda.bar/face_podpis.png">

          <p class="icons"><a href="bhttps://www.facebook.com/loft.hall.7?ref=br_rs">
          <img class="social1" src="bhttp://contrabanda.bar/fb_icon.png"></a>
          <a href="bhttps://www.instagram.com/thelofthall/"><img class="social2" src="bhttp://contrabanda.bar/in_icon.png"></a>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td class="seconddiv">
        <p class="person"><font size="4" color="#6f8094" face="Arial" ><strong>Александр Великанов</strong></font></p>
        <p class="whois"><font size="1" color="#000000" face="Arial" font-family="bold">Руководитель отдела продаж</font></p>
        <p class="adress"><font size="1" color="#000000" face="Arial" font-family="bold"><a class="phone" href="tel:79852002121">+7 (985) 200-21-21</a> | <a class="phone" href="tel:74951201905">+7 (495) 120-19-05</a><br> <nobr><a class="phone" href="https://yandex.ru/maps/-/CZROnSId">БЦ "Симонов Плаза" | Ленинская Слобода ул. 26</a></nobr> <br> av@lofthall.ru | info@lofthall.ru</font></p>
        <p class="site"><font size="1" color="#6f8094" face="Arial">WWW.LOFTHALL.RU</font></p>
      </td>
       <td rowspan="2" class="fourdiv" >
         <a href="http://loft2.lofthall.ru/"><img src="http://contrabanda.bar/two.png"></a> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="thirddiv">
         <a href="http://loft2.lofthall.ru/"><img  src="http://contrabanda.bar/one.png"></a>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Насколько я помню, необходимо вынести стили в атрибуты элементов (<div style="">) - стили в head игнорируются

Answer (score 3):

При верстке писем используются только Inline-стили, применяемые непосредственно к тегам.

[Верстка email рассылок от А до Я для чайников](https://habrahabr.ru/post/252279/)

Большинство почтовых клиентов не видят стили расположенные в `head`, поэтому и отображение везде разное будет.

Плюс [Поддержка в различных почтовых клиентах](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).